# Custom Excel import into sharepoint list

Tags: excel, import

I have a requirement like this.
In Sharepoint there is  list (lets call it master list) It has all required columns with their respective types. A user need to be able to import data from Excel file (single Sheet - with the same set of fields as sharepoint list). During that import data on a list should be deleted and replaced with new coming from Excel file).

Which Sharepoint solution would be best for this requirement?
Should I create SharepointHosted-AddIn or ProviderHosted-App or webpart or something else.

I was reading about that and am very confused.

Comment: have you tried to use "Import Spreadsheet" ? also what do you mean by (During that import data on a list should be deleted and replaced with new coming from Excel file).

Comment: Yes I have tried it but the idea is to have one list all the time with data being updated. That is clear the list and import new data every time. Thats why "Import spreadsheet" isn't a good solution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't import an Excel file to an existing SharePoint list. Out of the box, the best option would probably to copy and paste your content from Excel to SharePoint Quick Edit mode. Have you tried?

If this doesn't work well, you might want to consider using 3rd party software, such as [SharePoint List Synchronizer](https://www.synchronizer-for-excel-and-sharepoint.com). Disclaimer: this product is edited by SoftFluent, my employer.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm looking for the way to build something like that myself.

Comment: OK I'm accepting this one as its almost the solution I was looking for. But at the end I have decided to build SharePoint Provider-hosted Add-in for this import. It was quiet easy to build and manipulate data using CSOM.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a PowerShell script. First convert the Excel to a CSV file and then by using a PowerShell script, you can import the records. There are many examples of PowerShell script online that can do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can import CSV data into sharepoint list using Import from CSV office app.
You can add this app from office 365 app store.

Site Contents -> New -> App -> SharePoint store -> Import Excel or CSV to List.

[image: Import from CSV]